# Copying two columns into rows in excel

Tags: excel

I have the following data.

```
column
A   B
1   Send 
5   Think 
8   Master 
9   Symbolic 
10  Removed
```

I want it copied into this way

```
Column
A        B          C          D          E        F           G    H
1        Send       5          Think      8        Master      9    Symbolic
```

I tried offset formula.  But it is not working.  I have attached screen of the same. 
[image]
Please help

Comment: I had success with the offset formula that pnuts provided.

Answer (score 0):

Despite OP's *I tried offset formula* it seems such does suit:

```
=OFFSET($A2,(COLUMN()-1)/2,ISEVEN(COLUMN()))
```